# How to implements some functions for a stack?

Tags: python, stack

I'm trying to implement these functions for a stack: push(S), isEmpty(S), top(S), nextToTop(S). It says syntax error. How to test it?

```
S= [1, 5, 13, 21]
def push(S):
    return S

def isEmpty(S):
    if S = []:
        print ("Empty String")
    else:
        print ("String is not empty")
def Top(S):
     if S = []:
         print ("Empty String")
    else:
        return S[0]

def nextToTop(S):
    if S = []:
        print ("String is not empty")
    else:
        return S[1]

print(push(S))
print(isEmpty(S))
print(Top(S))
print(nextToTop(S))
```

Comment: `It says syntax error.` you should fix your syntax then.

Comment: first read error message - there is information what is the problem and in which line. Sometimes `syntax error` is in line above.

Comment: Python syntax errors will point to which line has the error.  If you don't understand them yet, then including the error you get when asking would be useful to any answerers.

Answer (score 1):

`S = []` is the the assignment operator where as `==` is the `conditional equal to` operator. Hence, your `if` condition for *checking the empty list* should be like `if S == []`.

The same behavior can be achieved by simply doing:

```
if S:   # check if S is not empty
    print "list is not empty"  # S is list, not string
else:
    print "list is empty"
```